# javascript indexOf not working with list data

Tags: javascript

I have a list of index positions in a variable called positions, I want to find the index of one of the positions like...

```
positions[0]
(2) [0, 0]

positions.indexOf([0,0]);
-1

var item = positions[0]
undefined

item
(2) [0, 0]0: 01: 0length: 2__proto__: Array(0)concat: ...

positions.indexOf(item);
0
```

What would be the way to use indexOf in this case?

Answer (score 3):

The `indexOf` method uses strict comparison to find its match. This is the same comparison algorithm used by `===`, and it compares *identity* of object types (like Array). So when you pass `[0,0]`, you're passing a new object with its own identity, so no match is found.

That's why it works when you search specifically for the item at index `0`. You're now finding the Array with the same identity.

To make it work the way you want, you'll need to use a custom object comparison that takes into account the members of the Array. JavaScript has nothing like this built in, but you'll find solutions if you search for "deep equality comparison".

Once you have the comparison function, you can use `.findIndex()` to run it on each object.

```
var data = [0, 0];
var result = positions.findIndex(function(item) {
  // return result of comparing `data` with `item`

  // This simple implementation assumes that all `item`s will be Arrays.
  return data.length === item.length &&
         item.every(function(n, i) { return n === data[i] });
});
```

---

Strictly speaking, *if* the members of `positions` are all Arrays with numbers as members, you could use `JSON.stringify()` to do the comparison. But don't trust it if the members being compared are of other object types. It may *seem* to work, but could fail without notice.

```
var data = JSON.stringify([0, 0]);
var result = positions.findIndex(function(item) {
  return data === JSON.stringify(item);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @blex, you're right. The OP seems to want the index. I'll update.